# Distinguish between two error occurring with `on error goto` and separately handle them

Tags: error-handling, ms-word, runtime-error, goto, onerror

I am working with three `Word Documents`.

1. Rough
2. CEEMEA & LATAM
3. Ticker Graveyard

At start only `Rough` Document is opened. I need to shift data from Rough to `CEEMEA & LATAM` and use `Ticker Graveyard` to match some queries, so both `CEEMEA & LATAM` `Ticker Graveyard` should already be opened.

for that I check both other documents are already open or not. if not then I need to open particular document using `Documents.Open`. for that I'm doing following **Updated Code**:

```
sub ErrHandling()

On Error GoTo PROBLEM
Windows("CEEMEA & LATAM").Activate ''''' Here checking CEEMEA & LATAM status
'''' after checking STATUS do some work on CEEMEA & LATAM '''''

Set doc = Application.Windows("Ticker Graveyard").Document ''''' Here checking Ticker Graveyard status
'''' after checking do some work on Ticker Graveyard '''''

Exit Sub
PROBLEM:
If Err.Number = 5941 Then
    Documents.Open FileName:="C:\Users\dell\Desktop\EMEA CEEMEA\CEEMEA & LATAM.docx" --- handling only CEEMEA & LATAM document

'''''' These lines handle Date in document while opening document''''
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=2
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.TypeText Format(Date, "MMMM dd, yyyy")
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Else
MsgBox "UNEXPECTED ERROR = " & Err.Number
Exit Sub
End If

Resume Next
End Sub
```

But the problem is as both checking point trigger same `Error Number` I cannot distinguish them using simple `on error goto` statement.

Now my question is how do I distinguish both errors? and how can I handle them separately? **If there is another way to handle that situation kindly share.**

Comment: Please also show us (as [mcve] the code that calls the `sub` in the question. As it stands, out-of-context, it's difficult to give advice. Right off-hand, though, I'd say the code should be structured differently, by checking the `Documents` collection whether the documents are present. Generally, it's a bad idea to use `Activate` to work with a particular document - better to use a `Document` object.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous strategies for handling the situation where the code needs to refer to a specific object which may or may not be present. Which approach is "best" is, in part, a philosophical consideration. The basic approaches are:

1. Triggering an error, then handling it. This is how the code in the question is designed. When using VBA it's also a valid approach as it can be relatively fast. For any .NET language, however, it will slow down the code appreciably and should not be used if there's any other possibility.
2. Iterating a collection to determine if the object in question is available. If the collection holds a lot of items this can be slower in VBA than the error handling approach. On the other hand, it tends to make code more easily understandable (in my opinion).

A strategy for both approaches is outlined below, based on the code in the question.

**Error handling**

More than one "label" (target for the error handler to jump to) can be used in a procedure, so it's possible to have a "label" for each separate document. So for each document a different error handler, with it's own "branch" of code is available.

```
On Error GoTo PROBLEM_CEEMA
Windows("CEEMEA & LATAM").Activate ''''' Here checking CEEMEA & LATAM status
On Error GoTo General
'''' after checking STATUS do some work on CEEMEA & LATAM '''''

On Error GoTo PROBLEM_TICKER
Set doc = Application.Windows("Ticker Graveyard").Document ''''' Here checking Ticker Graveyard status
On Error GoTo General
'''' after checking do some work on Ticker Graveyard '''''

Exit Sub

PROBLEM_CEEMA:
  If Err.Number = 5941 Then
    Documents.Open FileName:="C:\Users\dell\Desktop\EMEA CEEMEA\Ticker Graveyard.docx" --- handling only Ticker document    
  Else
    MsgBox "UNEXPECTED ERROR = " & Err.Number
    Exit Sub
  End If

Resume Next 

PROBLEM_TICKER:
  If Err.Number = 5941 Then
    Documents.Open FileName:="C:\Users\dell\Desktop\EMEA CEEMEA\CEEMEA & LATAM.docx" --- handling only CEEMEA & LATAM document    
  Else
    MsgBox "UNEXPECTED ERROR = " & Err.Number
    Exit Sub
  End If

Resume Next 

PROBLEM_General:
  'General, non-document-related error handling
End Sub
```

**Iterating the Documents collection**

The Word application keeps a running list of opened documents in the `Documents` collection. It's possible to use a `For...Each` (or `For`) loop to run through the collection and compare the document name. This can be done in a separate function so that the code doesn't need to be repeated.

```
Sub Test
  Dim doc1 as Document, file1 as String
  Dim doc2 as Document, file2 as String

  file1 = "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\EMEA CEEMEA\CEEMEA & LATAM.docx"
  file2 = "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\EMEA CEEMEA\Ticker Graveyard.docx"

  If not IsDocumentOpen(file1) Then
    Set doc1 = Documents.Open(FileName:=file1)
  End If

  If not IsDocumentOpen(file2) Then
    Set doc2 = Documents.Open(FileName:=file2)
  End If
End Sub

Function IsDocumentOpen(fileName as String) as Boolean
  Dim doc as Word.Document
  Dim isOpen as Boolean

  isOpen = false
  For Each doc in Documents
     IF doc.Name = fileName Then
        isOpen = true
     End If
  Next
  IsDocumentOpen = isOpen
End Function
```

Comment: I am interested in your second suggestion, as it is more efficient, but I had problem implementing it. after opening a document I need to add additional code (i.e insert `Date`) to that particular document. if document is already opened then I don't need these additional code. I will mention this situation in my original question. Can you accommodate this to your second suggestion? also can the `Function IsDocumentOpen` merge into `sub test()`?